# installing cucumber using bundler

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems

I am using cucumber and ruby. I was reading the book the cucumber book using Windows 8 where they tell you to install Ruby and next install Bundler. I opened a CMD and executed the command `gem install bundler` which worked. The next step is to install cucumber and RSpec, here is where I don't now what to do. Here is the text:

> Cucumber is packaged as a gem and can be installed by running gem install
>   cucumber. However, most of the examples in this book assume you install it
>   via Bundler, which means having a Gemfile in the root directory of your project.
>   Most of the examples also assume you’ll use RSpec,1 so you’ll need that in
>   your Gemfile too:

```
source :rubygems
group :test do
gem 'cucumber', '1.1.3'
gem 'rspec-expectations', '2.7.0'
end
```

I wrote the code above using notepad, but don't now which file extention to use. (`.gem` maybe?)

Next, do I have to first install cucumber and the RSpec, then use the gemfile?
I have tried to use the next code bundle install, in order to install cucumber, and get the message

> Could not locate Gemfile

But I tested `cucumber --help` and noticed that cucumber is installed. Any ideas on how to install using Bundler? Or does it work?

Comment: Try using this source line for your Gemfile: `source 'https://rubygems.org'`, then run `bundle install`.  As far as the extention, your Gemfile is simply named `Gemfile` with no extension.

Comment: when i save the gemfile in the note pad, it save like a txt file, een when a used save as, tipe of file: all files,  and a have try using the source 'https://rubygems.org' no luck

Comment: That is a tooling problem, really.  Find a better editor for writing code.   [This stackoverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9265294/485864) is a pretty good listing of tools available.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is hinting at editor problems.  You need to be able to save the `Gemfile` as that without any extension.

Using an appropriate editor helps.

[This stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9265294/485864) has a decent list.

As my comment stated

> > Try using this source line for your Gemfile: *source 'https://rubygems.org'*, then run bundle install. As far as the extension, your Gemfile is simply named *Gemfile* with no extension.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have bundler installed, you can generate a Gemfile by running `bundle init`, which will produce a Gemfile like the following:

```
# A sample Gemfile
source "https://rubygems.org"

# gem "rails"
```

You can then modify the Gemfile to suit your needs and run `bundle install`.  For more info, check the [bundler](http://bundler.io/v1.7/gemfile.html) documentation.